# Selecting a certain word in a TKinter text field

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Good day! There is a question that torments me for the last few days and I can not find a solution to it. I have written a program that translates certain difficult words in the text.The structure of the final result is as follows:

`word word {translate of the word} word word word`

I would really like to apply some styles to the word in curly brackets (change the color for example) but I can't do anything.

The code that generates the text:
https://pastebin.com/SGgV9NUv

I've tried to change the text color using ANSI. It worked, but the color display itself doesn't work in the TKinter text block (I didn't know that at first).
Then I tried rewriting the main function code to include color. Nothing worked.
Finally I came across tag_add - it really does something but I can't get it to highlight specific places in the text! They are not static and so I would like it to read a variable and substitute it into the tagging code. But I can't get it to do that.

```
def highlight_translation(translated_text):
#     position = re.search("\{.*\}", translated_text)
#     positions = []
#     positions.append(position.span())
#     text_area.tag_config('unknown_word', background="yellow", foreground="red")
#     for hl in positions:
#         text_area.tag_add("unknown_word", hl)
```

I am using Python 3.11.4 and a Linux operating system (Fedora 37)